# Unable to understand the "Kill" program of linux

Tags: c, linux, kill

Here is a very small "kill" related program .The program is executing but am unable to figure out the code.Can any one please make me understand the code below.

```
int main(int argc ,char **argv)
{
  if(argc < 2)
  {
    printf("usage : ./kill PID");
    return -1;
  }
  kill(atoi(argv[1]),SIGKILL);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SIGKILL` is, in general, a bad thing to send since it prevents the process from cleaning up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it just checks to see if an argument has been provided. `if(argc < 2)` means are there less than two arguments to the program. Note that the program name itself is an argument too, which is why it's `argc < 2` and not `argc < 1`. Once this has been determined the builtin `kill` function is called. The first argument to this method is an integer, which is why the second argument (the PID, represented as a string) is parsed to an integer with `atoi`. The second argument to `kill` is the signal, in this case `SIGKILL`. Other signals, such as `SIGHUP` could also have been used, but since this program "kills", it uses `SIGKILL`.

Answer (score 3):

it takes the first argument to the program (`argv[1]`), converts it to an integer (`atoi` - ascii to integer) and sends the SIGKILl (9) signal to the process with that process id.

`if(argc < 2)` simply checks if there were enough parameters provided, and `return -1` exits the program with an exit code `!= 0` to signal unsuccessful termination.

Comment: thank u sir ,but sir one more doubt can u pls tell me why argc<2 and return value -1.

Comment: @Sai Kiran: That checks that you supplied the correct command line arguments. If not, it prints a usage message and exits with an error status (-1).