# Kill command in c-programming

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to understand the “Kill” program of linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134848/unable-to-understand-the-kill-program-of-linux)

Hi All,
Can anyone explain me how this program works.
Please explain what each line do.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<signal.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("usage: ./kill PID");
        return -1;
    }

    kill(atoi(argv[1]), SIGKILL);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `Please explain what each line do.` Excuse me?

Comment: The program takes a process id that the user entered from the command line and runs the kill command on it, so that the process is terminated. As for a description of every line...I suggest picking up a good C or C++ book, or checking the vast number of tutorials available.

Answer (score 2):

The line `kill(atoi(argv[1]), SIGKILL);` sends a [SIGKILL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL) signal to the process with the specified ID; this should cause it to terminate.  The `atoi(argv[1])` part converts the string from the command-line parameters into an integer.

For the rest, I recommend picking up a beginner's guide to C.

Comment: what about the below mentioned line.int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{ 
    if (argc < 2) 
    { 
        printf("usage: ./kill PID"); 
        return -1;

Comment: 5 years later... so you understand what int main(int argc, char **argv) { if (argc < 2) { printf("usage: ./kill PID"); return -1; means now?